# minimo comun multiplo de tres numeros usando la descomposicion de primos en python

Tags: python-2.7

```
 print('Algoritmo para sacar minimo comun multiplo de tres');
 
numeros_str = []
numeros_str= input('digite tres numeros separados por espacio').split(' ')  #split(' ') reemplaza los espacios por una coma 

numeros = [int(x) for x in numeros_str]

def descomponer(n):
    primos = []

    for i in range(2, n+1):

        while n % i == 0:
                primos.append(i)
                n = n / i
    return primos    


lista = numeros
primos_1 = descomponer(lista[0]) 
primos_2 = descomponer(lista[1]) 
primos_3 = descomponer(lista[2])
arrayFinal = []

print(primos_1) 
print(primos_2)
print(primos_3)  



for i in primos_1:   
    if i not in primos_2:
        if i not in primos_3:
            arrayFinal.append(i)       


for j in primos_2:   
    if j not in primos_1:
        if j not in primos_3:
            arrayFinal.append(j)


for p in primos_3:   
    if p not in primos_1:
        if p not in primos_2:
            arrayFinal.append(p)
                 
print(arrayFinal)
```

Ya logre hacer la descomposición en primos de los 3 números dados por el usuario y guardar cada descomposicion en una lista. Pero no se como comparar las tres listas de números, si no hay números que coincidan en ninguna lista, colocar estos en una lista nueva (arrayFinal) pero si hay números repetidos entre las listas colocar en arrayFinal los numeros de la lista que mas se repiten. ejemplo:

```
    l1=[2, 5, 5, 17]
    l2=[2, 2, 2, 5]
    l3=[2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5]

    listaNueva = [2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 17]
```

para al final multiplicar los numeros de listaNueva y asi obtener el m.c.m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución:

```
l1=[2, 5, 5, 17]
l2=[2, 2, 2, 5]
l3=[2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5]

# El diccionario totales_factor tiene por llave el factor
# y por valor el número de repeticiones máxima.
totales_factor = {factor:0 for factor in set(l1 + l2 + l3)}

for lista in l1, l2, l3:

    # Formar diccionario con llave factor y valor el número
    # de veces que se repite en esta lista.
    totales_lista = {k: lista.count(k) for k in set(lista)}

    # Comparar este diccionario parcial contra el diccionario
    # total, conservardo el mayor valor para cada factor
    for factor, repeticiones in totales_lista.items():
        if repeticiones > totales_factor[factor]:
            totales_factor[factor] = repeticiones

#   Calcular el m.c.m.
resultado = 1
for factor, repeticiones in totales_factor.items():
    resultado *= factor ** repeticiones
print("m.c.m = ", resultado)
```

*Análisis*

La idea es usar un diccionario para llevar la cuenta de los factores y sus repeticiones. La llave es el factor y el valor es la cantidad de veces que aparece ese factor.

El diccionario `totales_factor` contendrá por cada factor el mayor número de repeticiones ocurridas dentro de alguna de las listas. Igualmente, `totales_lista` contendrá las repeticiones para una lista.

Para inicializar la lista a cero usamos:

```
totales_factor = {factor:0 for factor in set(l1 + l2 + l3)}
```

donde usamos `set()` para obtener extraer los factores de la lista total y usarlos como llave del diccionario.

Para la segunda lista usamos `set()` para obtener los factores sin duplicados y luego `lista.count()` para contarlos y crear la entrada en el diccionario.

```
totales_lista = {k: lista.count(k) for k in set(lista)}
```

y luego se actualiza el diccionario general:

```
for factor, repeticiones in totales_lista.items():
    if repeticiones > totales_factor[factor]:
        totales_factor[factor] = repeticiones
```

Para calcular el m.c.m., se recorre el diccionario general evaluando cada entrada como `factor ** valor`, es decir, elevando el factor a la potencia según el número de repeticiones.

```
#   Calcular el m.c.m.
resultado = 1
for factor, repeticiones in totales_factor.items():
    resultado *= factor ** repeticiones
print("m.c.m = ", resultado)
```

produce:

```
m.c.m =  20400

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Que buena solucion la de los diccionarios, lo tenia en la cabeza pero no sabia como desarrollarlo, estuve probando con diferetentes listas y al parecer para algunas falla: l1=[2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5]
l2=[2, 281]
l3=[2, 3, 3, 7, 29]                                                                                                                               Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Camilo Nieto\Desktop\m_c_m\mcm.py", line 49, in <module>
    if repeticiones > totales_factor[factor]:
KeyError: 281